# Топики в списке вопросов выглядят осветлёнными, как бы не активными

Tags: дефект, поддержка

Почему иногда топики выглядят "осветлёнными", как бы не активными? 
Вот сообщения на картинке: [первое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/827724/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-excel-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4-nodejs) и [второе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/827723/%d0%92-%d1%87%d1%91%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%8f%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0-embedded-linux). Особой разницы по содержанию между ними я не заметил.

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что в вопросе есть игнорируемая вами метка.

[Expressing Your Tag Preferences](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/10/21/expressing-your-tag-preferences/) .

Comment: Верно. Вопрос - как она туда попала? - задавать не буду.